# Why does Intellij Idea highlights a resource csv file contents in red?

Tags: intellij-idea

In my Spring Boot application in `resources` folder there is a `csv` file. When I open it in IntelliJ 2019.3 all content of the file is red, why?

[image]

Comment: Do you use any custom plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `Rainbow CSV` plugin was making all `csv` file contents in red. After disabling it text became black again.